# What's the proper way to link to a CSS file within my GitHub?

Tags: github

For example I can access a twitter resource from the following

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css

When I try to access the 'raw' file from my own repository I get

https://raw.github.com/nodeninja/book/master/chapter02/bootstrap/public/stylesheets/docs.css

Which doesn't work correctly in a web page I'm guessing because of https.  What's the correct way to do this link?

Comment: Works just fine for me. It's a horrible practice to link directly to files in your SCM though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub have a pages facility for doing this

http://help.github.com/pages/

This is what I wanted

http://nodeninja.github.com/book/chapter02/docs.css